# Is it possible to create my own certified to run a java applet?

Tags: java, applet, certificate, x509certificate

I need to control a joystick to a project.
The only solution so far is to use a java applet, because my program is Web running in a apache server.

Some clients, need an joystick for an operation, Obviously for that the applet need permission.
After a week of test and have signed my applet i still having security problems, then i tried with netbeans and saw this warning:

> Warning: Unsigned and self-signed WebStart Applications and Applets are deprecated from JDK7u21 onwards due to security reasons. To ensure future correct functionality please sign WebStart Applications and Applets using trusted certificate.

I will not pay for a CA, My question is if it's is possible to i create my CA and install in the client PC?
IF it is possible, there is some tutorial to do that?

Comment: https://workaround.org/certificate-authority

Comment: Eg. [StartSSL](http://www.startssl.com/?app=1) offers free certificates.

Comment: 1/ your signing certificate needs to have the Extended Key Usage extension with the code signing flag. If not you will probably have an exception or at least a warning when signing and verifying the signature. 2/ there is a HTML5 gamepad API available on modern web browsers

Comment: The Gamepad API dosen't work with joystick, at least the ones I tried, that was my fisrt option!